# C programming: writing directory file names into an array, strange symbols appear

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm trying to put the names of each of the files in a directory into an array. The code seems to work well up until I print the array itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main ()
{
    char directory_name[10];
    DIR *ptr;
    int n, i;

    n = 0;
    i = 0;

    //Ask user for directory name
    struct dirent *directory;
    printf ("Enter Directory Name:\t");
    scanf ("%s", directory_name);
    ptr = opendir (directory_name);
    printf ("\nDirectory %s\n", directory_name);

    while ((directory = readdir (ptr)) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp (directory->d_name, ".")
            || !strcmp (directory->d_name, "..")) {

        } else {
            n++;
        }
    }

    rewinddir (ptr);

    char *filesList[n];

    //Put file names into the array
    while ((directory = readdir (ptr)) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp (directory->d_name, ".")
            || !strcmp (directory->d_name, "..")) {
        } else {
            filesList[i] = (char *) malloc (strlen (directory->d_name) + 1);
            strncpy (filesList[i], directory->d_name,
                    strlen (directory->d_name));
            i++;
        }
    }
    rewinddir (ptr);

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        printf ("%s\n", filesList[i]);
    }

    closedir (ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

The filesList prints, but at the end of the print out, it adds another line with these symbols:

)─ìD$â└┴Φ┴αëE╨Θï

I would like to remove these symbols from the array. However, since I don't know what they are or where they are coming from, I have no idea where to even start. I am very new to C, so I apologize if this is a beginner question.

I would like to clarify that the program is recognizing these symbols as a file name, even though there is no file by that name in the directory. The index is increased as if it were a file.

Comment: 99% of the time this is a failure to properly NULL terminate a string and you walked off the end of your buffer. Why is `directory_name` a comically tiny ten character buffer? Try using something like `PATH_MAX` if it's defined for you, or 255 otherwise.

Comment: `char directory_name[10];` 10 characters (9 if you include the `\0`) is very short for a directory name. This buffer might be overflowing, hence the nonsense data. I would bump it up to at least 250 characters. Also, there is no warning when the condition with 2 `strcmp` calls fail; this means that some of the pointers in `fileList` might be invalid.

Comment: You are off by one: you allocated `char *filesList[n]`, but iterate 0..n, inclusive: `for(i=0; i<=n; i++)`. Use `i < n` to fix this. Don't forget to delete the question, otherwise someone would provide a useless answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use *magic numbers* in your code:

```
char directory_name[10];
```

If you need a constant, define one, or if an appropriate constant is already provided for the specific application, use that instead, e.g.

```
#ifndef PATH_MAX        /* declare constants as required */
#define PATH_MAX 4096
#endif

#define NFILE 128
...
char directory_name[PATH_MAX] = "",
    ...
```

You can't be absolutely sure where the origin of any of your problems are because you fail to *VALIDATE* any of the required returns. All functions except `void` provide a return that can be used to indicate success or failure -- use them, e.g.

```
    /* open and VALIDATE directory with opendir */
    ptr = opendir (directory_name);
    if (!ptr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: directory open failed '%s'.\n", 
                directory_name);
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("\nDirectory open '%s'\n", directory_name);
```

This is an **absolute must** for *User Input*.

Your filled array indexes are between `0` and `n-1`, so your indexing of `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)` invokes *Undefined Behavior* by reading beyond the bounds of your VLA. Use `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Instead of making two passes over your directory, (the first to count the number of files, rewind, and the second to read the filenames), just allocate some reasonable number of pointers to char initially, keep track of the number you fill, and `realloc` when you reach the current limit. The following code does just that (as well as cleaning up your user input -- which should be simplified and made more robust by using `fgets` instead of `scanf`), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <limits.h>

#ifndef PATH_MAX        /* declare constants as required */
#define PATH_MAX 4096
#endif

#define NFILE 128

/* simple function to empty stdin.
 * mandatory when taking user input with scanf
 */
void empty_stdin()
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int main (void) {

    DIR *ptr = NULL;
    struct dirent *directory = NULL;
    char directory_name[PATH_MAX] = "",
        **files = NULL;     /* using pointer to pointer to char */
    size_t i, n = 0, nptr = NFILE;

    /* prompt for and VALIDATE input of directory_name */
    for (;;) {     /* loop until valid input received or user cancels */
        int rtn;
        printf ("Enter Directory Name: ");
        rtn = scanf ("%s", directory_name);
        if (rtn == 1) {     /* good input, proceed */
            empty_stdin();
            break;
        }
        else if (rtn == EOF) {  /* user canceled input */
            fprintf (stderr, "user canceled input.\n");
            return 1;
        }   /* handle other error */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        empty_stdin();
    }

    /* open and VALIDATE directory with opendir */
    ptr = opendir (directory_name);
    if (!ptr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: directory open failed '%s'.\n", 
                directory_name);
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("\nDirectory open '%s'\n", directory_name);

    /* allocate and VALIDATE nptr pointer for filenames */
    files = calloc (nptr, sizeof *files);
    if (!files) {
        perror ("pointer allocation failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each filename, allocate/VALIDATE storage, copy to files[n],
     * check total pointer allocation, realloc as required.
     */
    while ((directory = readdir (ptr)) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp (directory->d_name, ".")    /* skip dot files */
            || !strcmp (directory->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        /* allocate VALIDATE storage for filename */
        files[n] = malloc (strlen (directory->d_name) + 1);
        if (!files[n]) {
            perror ("memory exhausted - filesList");
            return 1;
        }
        strcpy (files[n++], directory->d_name); /* copy filename */
        /* check if ptr limit reached, if so realloc 2x pointers */
        if (n == nptr) {
            void *tmp = realloc (files, nptr * 2 * sizeof *files);
            if (!tmp) {
                perror ("realloc failed - files");
                break;  /* files still points to original block */
            }
            files = tmp;
            /* optional - zero all newly added memory */
            memset (files + nptr, 0, nptr * sizeof *files);
            nptr *= 2;  /* increment number currently allocated */
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* indexes are 0 -> n-1 */
        printf ("%s\n", files[i]);
        free (files[i]);        /* don't forget to free memory */
    }
    free (files);   /* free pointers */

    closedir (ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readdir_alloc
Enter Directory Name: dat
Directory open 'dat'
lastchgcol.txt
arrinpt.txt
...
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/readdir_alloc
==10547== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10547== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10547== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10547== Command: ./bin/readdir_alloc
==10547==
Enter Directory Name: dat
Directory open 'dat'
lastchgcol.txt
arrinpt.txt
...
==10547==
==10547== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10547==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10547==   total heap usage: 248 allocs, 248 frees, 38,729 bytes allocated
==10547==
==10547== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10547==
==10547== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10547== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Using `fgets` is the recommended way to take user input. `scanf` if full of pitfall that trap new C programmers. `fgets` requires no more than you check the return and then overwrite the trailing `'\n'` included in the buffer with a *nul-terminating* character. You could remove the entire `for` loop that loops until valid input is received using `scanf` with the following simplified code using `fgets`:

```
    size_t len;
    printf ("Enter Directory Name: ");
    if (!fgets (directory_name, PATH_MAX, stdin)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to read directory_name.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    len = strlen (directory_name);
    if (len && directory_name[len - 1] == '\n')
        directory_name[--len] = 0;
    else if (len + 1 == PATH_MAX) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: directory_name too long.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
strncpy (filesList[i],directory->d_name, strlen(directory->d_name) );\
```

will copy the name WITHOUT the terminating NUL, so when you later print it, you'll see extra garbage on the end of the string.  Use `strcpy` instead.  Better yet, use `strdup` to allocate and copy the string in one step.

Comment: btw, instead of strlen, you could have used `directory->d_reclen`. Or `d_reclen + 1` in case of `strncpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Append a terminating null character at the end. You can use strdup() to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

After declare `char *filesList[n];` init last pointer to `NULL` `filesList[n] = NULL;` then change your loop to this

```
for(i=0; filesList[i]; i++) {
   printf("%s\n", filesList[i]);
}
```

You have that garbage because you try to access pointer that point to some part of memory that you not initialize.
For example you have directory Music/ with four files in it, file1, file2, file3, file4. So your initialization would be similar to this:

```
filesList[0] file4 copy
filesList[1] file2 copy
filesList[2] file1 copy
filesList[3] file3 copy
filesList[4] -> point to some uninit part of memory
```

Then you in loop print filesList[4] and it show garbage.

Also in statements like this  it would be better to use `continue` not empty body:

```
if (!strcmp(directory->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(directory->d_name, ".."))
{
    continue;
}
```

And also you can replace `strncpy()` with `snprintf()` It also always includes the null terminator `'\0'`, unless the buffer size is 0 but you can check it or just add `'\0'` manually

```
filesList[i][strlen(directory->d_name)] = '\0';
```